# Scala JSON: Collect and parse an array of arrays with lift

Tags: json, scala

I have a JSON that has array of arrays. Like this:

```
{
  "id": "532242",
  "text": "Some text here. And Here",
  "analysis": {
    "exec": "true",
    "rowID": "always",
    "sentences": {
      "next": null,
      "data": [{
          "sequence": "1",
          "readability_score_lexical": null,
          "readability_score_syntax": null,
          "tokens": [{
              "word": "Some",
              "lemma": "Some"

            },
            {
              "word": "text",
              "lemma": "text"

            }
          ]
        },


        {
          "sequence": "3",
          "readability_score_lexical": null,
          "readability_score_syntax": null,
          "tokens": [{
              "word": "and",
              "lemma": "And"

            },
            {
              "word": "here",
              "lemma": "here"

            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The structure is pretty complicated, but I cannot do anything on this side because is the response from an API.

What I need is to get a list `"tokens"` objects.

I did this with lift-web-json:

```
case class Token(word:String, lemma:String)
implicit val formats: Formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
val jsonObj = net.liftweb.json.parse(json)
val tokens = (jsonObj \\ "tokens").children
for (el <- tokens) {
        val m = el.extract[Token]
        println(s"Word ${m.word} and ${m.lemma}")
    }
```

but it says:

```
net.liftweb.json.MappingException: No usable value for word
Do not know how to convert JArray(List(JField(word,JString(Some)), JField(word,JString(text))))
[...]
Caused by: net.liftweb.json.MappingException: Do not know how to convert JArray(List(JField(word,JString(Some)), JField(word,JString(text)))) into class java.lang.String
```

And I don't understand how could I make it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get what you expect by replacing:

```
val tokens = (jsonObj \\ "tokens").children
for (el <- tokens) {
  val m = el.extract[Token]
  println(s"Word ${m.word} and ${m.lemma}")
}
```

with:

```
val tokens = for {
  // tokenList are:
  // JArray(List(JObject(List(JField(word,JString(Some)), JField(lemma,JString(Some)))), JObject(List(JField(word,JString(text)), JField(lemma,JString(text))))))
  // JArray(List(JObject(List(JField(word,JString(and)), JField(lemma,JString(And)))), JObject(List(JField(word,JString(here)), JField(lemma,JString(here))))))
  tokenList <- (jsonObj \\ "tokens").children
  // subTokenList are:
  // List(JObject(List(JField(word,JString(Some)), JField(lemma,JString(Some)))), JObject(List(JField(word,JString(text)), JField(lemma,JString(text)))))
  // List(JObject(List(JField(word,JString(and)), JField(lemma,JString(And)))), JObject(List(JField(word,JString(here)), JField(lemma,JString(here)))))
  JArray(subTokenList) <- tokenList
  // liftToken are:
  // JObject(List(JField(word,JString(Some)), JField(lemma,JString(Some))))
  // JObject(List(JField(word,JString(text)), JField(lemma,JString(text))))
  // JObject(List(JField(word,JString(and)), JField(lemma,JString(And))))
  // JObject(List(JField(word,JString(here)), JField(lemma,JString(here))))
  liftToken <- subTokenList
  // token are:
  // Token(Some,Some)
  // Token(text,text)
  // Token(and,And)
  // Token(here,here)
  token = liftToken.extract[Token]

} yield token
```

Comment: .... how did you do?! That was more complicated than expected... and you succeeded . Great job.. I wonder if there is a easiest way, though. But it does its job. Thank you

Comment: net.liftweb.json._ objects surprisingly implement pretty neat toString methods, which gives a good understanding of the full structure of what you get. That's what gave me the comments at each step. I'm not used to lift, so my guess is there probably is a more elegant solution.